# Vue.js webapp not accessible under localhost:<port>

Tags: express, vue.js, networking, localhost, hostname

so I have this Vue.js webapp which I developed on one PC, where I could always access it via either `localhost:<portnr>`, `127.0.0.1:<portnr>` or `<ip>:<portnr>`.

Now I work on another PC and the project is running fine so far, the problem just is that if I enter the url with localhost or 127.0.0.1 into the browser I will get an **"unable to connect error"**.

If I use the PCs ip or its hostname in the url I can visit the page as I normal.
I wonder what the problem could be. I don't know much about networking but as the PC before probably did not have a hostname set I thought maybe this could be a problem?

When starting the project via `npm run serve` I get the output

```
App running at:
  - Local:   http://<host_name>:5050/ 
  - Network: http://<ip>:5050/
```

**On the other pc it used to print localhost instead of the hostname at the url for local access.**
Thank you for any hint on how to solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after asking the question, I found a similar one [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/npm-run-serve-is-not-defaulting-to-localhost/88007/14) for everyone that has a similar issue.

To summarize the solution for me was to **add --host 0.0.0.0 to the npm run serve command in the package.json** so that the line looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

After this the output when running the command changed back to displaying localhost and I can access the page again via `localhost:<portnr>`.

I can't see any disadvantage in doing this simple fix. If there is, I will be glad to hear about a better solution!

Comment: I have a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898563/app-running-on-network-unavailable-vue-js Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to see you have local DNS server setting problem on the pc.

- ***Windows***

Open `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file with `notepad` or other editors as `administrator`.
Maybe the file looks like this:

```
... ... ...
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
```

You will need to uncomment 2 bottom lines if `localhost` wasn't be bound on ***Windows***

- ***Unix(Linux/macOS)***

Open `/etc/hosts` file with `nano` or other editors with `sudo` privilege.

You should get something similar to the below. If not, please make it like this.

```
##
# Host Database
# ... ... ...

127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: I checked this and the file seemed to be correct, thanks for the detailed explanation though!