# App running on network unavailable vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, web

I don't know what I've done to my pc, but I can't run vue app on network anymore
[image]

Can somebody tell me how to fix my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829363/how-do-i-disable-running-an-app-on-the-local-network-when-using-vue-cli is your vue config devserver set like this by any chance?

Comment: I don't have a vue.config.js

Comment: Than you have to create your own ```vue.config.js``` to solve this problem!

Comment: @B0BBY what it should look like?